# Cauchy’s Theorem without Green's Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can we proof Cauchy’s Integral Theorem for analytic functions without resorting to Green's theorem?

We have function $f(z)=z^n$ and Jordan curve $C$. We can state curve integral $\int_C f(z)\space dz$ as Riemann's sum, and then saparate real and imaginary parts. Does it always follow that the curve integral vanishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can prove the theorem in other ways. For example you can show that any continuous function on a convex open set that is holomorphic on the set minus one point has a primitive, with a clever decomposition of triangles inside the domain.

The answer to your second question is "no", unless the curve is closed. But the sentence "We can state curve integral $\int_Cf(z)\,dz$ as Riemann's sum, and then saparate real and imaginary parts." is upside down: first real and imaginary parts, and then Riemann sums (if you really want to consider them).